# How to write this query have 4 quarters and value is negative

Tags: mysql

Table_a

<kbd>Symbol</kbd><kbd>Quarter</kbd>  <kbd>Value</kbd>       

<kbd>S1</kbd>        <kbd>Q1</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            

<kbd>S1</kbd>        <kbd>Q2</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            

<kbd>S1</kbd>        <kbd>Q3</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            

<kbd>S1</kbd>        <kbd>Q4</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            


<kbd>S2</kbd>        <kbd>Q1</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            



<kbd>S2</kbd>        <kbd>Q3</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            



<kbd>S3</kbd>        <kbd>Q1</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            


<kbd>S3</kbd>        <kbd>Q3</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            


<kbd>S3</kbd>        <kbd>Q4</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>            


<kbd>S3</kbd>        <kbd>Q2</kbd>          <kbd>-1</kbd>

From Table_a, I want to get the symbols where Quarter has Q1 and Q2 and Q3 and Q4 Value negative.

So the result should be S1 and S3.

```
select symbol 
from Table_a 
where Quarter='A' and 
      Quarter='B' and 
      Quarter='C' and 
      Quarter='D' and Value<0 
group by symbol
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select symbol
from Table_a
where value < 0
group by symbol
having max(case when quarter = 'Q1' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when quarter = 'Q2' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when quarter = 'Q3' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when quarter = 'Q4' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01bb3/1)

Comment: You miss the negative condition

Comment: good job now, +1. One suggestion only - you can add an `S4` set in your SQLFiddle which has 4 quarters but some with positive values to confirm all conditions

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bitwise aggregate like this...

```
select symbol
from Table_a
GROUP BY symbol
HAVING BIT_OR(
    CASE
      WHEN Quarter = 'Q1' AND Value < 0 THEN 1
      WHEN Quarter = 'Q2' AND Value < 0 THEN 2
      WHEN Quarter = 'Q3' AND Value < 0 THEN 4
      WHEN Quarter = 'Q4' AND Value < 0 THEN 8
      ELSE 16
    END
  ) = 15;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a311/10)

Edit: Props to @Kirill Slatin for his suggestion in the comments.

Comment: In this case I would put `BIT_OR(` inside `having` clause and remove in `SELECT` to avoid irrelevant information in output